# Uitableview showing row behind HeaderView ios

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I'm working on `UITableView`.

In that when there is one row in the tableview at that time I'm getting weird. The first row hides behind headerView of `UITableView`.

As you can see in below image [image]

This is what happening. I'm using autolayout and having constraint also. I can't understand where exactly the issue is.

Comment: We also can't understand the exact issue unless you show us implementation.

Comment: Try by setting automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets property of tableview to false.

Comment: Is this setup as a `headerView` of `tableView` (the property), header view of a section, or a separate view added to view hierarchy?

Comment: @sasquatch i implement the tableview as regular demo of uitableview. nothing much more. What exactly you want to know about implementation ?

Comment: @iamyogish how can i set that i already added this line to code. 
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = NO;

Comment: @Losiowaty i used viewforHeaderinsection method to show header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks @ALL For giving your answers to my question.

Actually there was constraint problem. I gave the constraint priority to low. and this causes the issue.

I changed it with Required. and it works now perfectly.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you have transparent headers - in case you have sticky headers, this might give you some problems when scrolling.

Your problem probably lies in the header height - check if the height your tableview returns for the header in the first section has the right height (and not 0 or 1 pixel).

Answer (score 0):

this might happen if your view's height for header is larger than the headers size.

Or it might happen if your cell is implemented in .xib and the contents are going above the coordinates of the visibility.

If you can post the implementation code and snapshots of your interface it might help us to give you more appropriate answer